# How do I add newline within text string to zipfile using python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, newline, zip

Writing text to a zipfile using python. Below if the section of code I am using to do this. I can't figure out what character I need to use to get it to add new lines to the zipfile.

```
if Count:
    TextX = "The following species are present:"
    blurb = "\r\nINSERT TABLE HERE\r\n\r\nSA* - South America\r\nNA** - North America\r\nCA*** - Central America"
else:
    TextX = "No species are present."
    blurb = ""
```

Right now "if Count" is true, the output in the document looks like this:

```
INSERT TABLE HERE  SA* - South America  NA** - North America  CA*** - Central America
```

I want it too look like this:

```
INSERT TABLE HERE

SA* - South America
NA** - North America
CA*** - Central America
```

Below is some other pertinent script snippet that might help troubleshoot. The script is 600+ lines long which is why I did not include the whole thing. Everyting works except this piece.

```
replaceText = {"TextSpecies" : TextX,
        "TEXTBLURB" : blurb}

template = zipfile.ZipFile("C:\\Template.docx")
response = zipfile.ZipFile(results, "a")

with open(template.extract("word/document.xml", databaseDir + "\\")) as tempXmlFile:
    tempXml = tempXmlFile.read()

for key in replaceText.keys():
    tempXml = tempXml.replace(str(key), str(replaceText.get(key)))

with open(databaseDir + "\\temp.xml", "w+") as tempXmlFile:
    tempXmlFile.write(tempXml)

for file in template.filelist:
    if not file.filename == "word/document.xml":
        response.writestr(file.filename, template.read(file))

response.write(databaseDir + "\\temp.xml", "word/document.xml")

response.close()
template.close()
```

Ideas as to how to add new lines? I tried \r, \n, \r\n, ^11. None worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the details you give, it is clear that you want to create a Word DOCX file. While a docx file is a zip file, it is a zip file with very specific content and specific rules for this content. Most of the files found are XML files, as is `word/document.xml`. Within XML files whitespace (including line breaks, regardless whether they are of the Unix \n or Windows persuasion \r\n) is normally irrelevant. Instead you have to create all the tags that Word expects and fill them with reasonable data.

I have put a very minimal `word/document.xml` file with two paragraphs here, so you see what I'm talking about (Word usually writes these files without any whitespace into a single line, I have formatted it here for easier reading):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing">
    <w:body>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="style0"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr></w:rPr>
                <w:t>This is the first paragraph.</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="style0"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr></w:rPr>
                <w:t>This is the second paragraph.</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="style0"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr></w:rPr>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr>
            <w:type w:val="nextPage"/>
            <w:pgSz w:h="16838" w:w="11906"/>
            <w:pgMar w:bottom="1134" w:footer="0" w:gutter="0" w:header="0" w:left="1134" w:right="1134" w:top="1134"/>
            <w:pgNumType w:fmt="decimal"/>
            <w:formProt w:val="false"/>
            <w:textDirection w:val="lrTb"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

It seems that each line is such a `<w:p>` tag and that for a new paragraph one would need to create a new instanc eof this tag with all the information filled in.

Comment: I can see I was not as clear as I needed to be. I have a MS Word template file called "Automated Response.docx" that has a TAG imbedded between two paragraphs called "TEXTBLURB". Using a python script, if a certain condition is met,  replace this tag with some text that contains newlines, otherwise, don't add the text between paragraphs. I can't figure out the python code needed to imbed newlines into the tag. I am still new to all this and still getting familiar with the correct syntax, so if I am not as clear as I need to be, I am sorry

Comment: Following what I wrote, you could try to insert  `'</w:t></w:r></w:p><w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="style0"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:rPr>/w:rPr><w:t>'` instead of `'\n'`. Not sure it qorks, but it'S worth a try.